# Libcurl and user-defined functions for receiving/sending

Tags: c++, winapi, libcurl

I have my own functions for receiving and sending data to the network, based on WinSock, but I really don't want to implement text protocols myself, such as HTTP/HTTPS. I would like some good library to do it for me, for example Libcurl.

However, for example, if I make a `GET` request using libcurl, libcurl uses its own send and receive functions, but I want to use my own functions instead.

Does libcurl allow, somehow, to replace its functions for receiving and sending to use other user-defined functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does libcurl allow, somehow, to replace its functions for receiving and sending to use other user-defined functions?

No, it does not.

Comment: very bad :( Please tell me, are there any libraries at all that allow you to do this?

Comment: @Optimus1 not that I'm aware of. What could your custom functions possibly be doing that the native functions are not already doing, and which won't corrupt the protocols in question?

Comment: my functions are asynchronous, whereas libcurl is synchronous and works on blocking calls, that is, slow.

Comment: @Optimus1 then you wouldn't be able to replace the functions anyway, since your functions don't even have the same semantics that the library is expecting from the native functions. That being said, libcurl has its own asynchronous functionality, via its multi-interface API.

Comment: Doesn't this answer my question: https://curl.se/libcurl/c/externalsocket.html and https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html ?

Comment: @Optimus1 no, that does not address what you are asking for. Yes, you can create your own socket and give it to libcurl (for example, to implement connection pooling), but you still can't perform your own read/write I/O on that socket, libcurl expects to do its own I/O. There is simply no option to replace libcurl's I/O with custom functions. As for `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`, that is used by libcurl to give you data it has received from the socket so you can then write the data to whatever custom storage you want (ie, an in-memory string, etc).

Comment: let me please raise this topic again :) How then can I explain this quote from Curl online book: ""There are numerous event based systems to select from out there, and libcurl is completely agnostic to which one you use. libevent, libev and libuv are three popular ones but you can also go directly to your operating system's native solutions such as epoll, kqueue, /dev/poll, pollset, Event Completion or I/O Completion Ports."" ?

Comment: @Optimus1 that quote is from "Driving with the 'multi_socket' interface". `multi-socket` is an advanced form of `multi-interface`, which I mentioned earlier. If you read that book section more carefully, it only describes **detecting events** on sockets (ie, monitoring *which* socket has data to read), it *DOES NOT* describe **performing I/O** using your own functions. libcurl is still responsible for the actual I/O. You tell libcurl which easy handles to transfer, then it tells you which socket(s) to monitor, then you tell libcurl which events happen on those sockets so it can act accordingly

Comment: it seems to me - this is exactly what I needed. Libcurl_easy_handle uses blocking sockets, and I needed asynchronous sockets together with IOCP and so that libcurl himself wrote to these sockets and read in them himself, but using IOCP.

Comment: @Optimus1 originally, you asked how to do your own I/O on libcurl sockets. That is NOT what this API allows you to do. But yes, libcurl *can* do its own asynchronous I/O. I told you that 4 months ago.

Comment: Apparently I formulated the question incorrectly from the very beginning. Of course, I meant that I wanted libcurl to read and write to sockets myself, but not to my own, but to mine: WSASocket`s. Only I cannot understand - libcurl works with WSASocket or not.

Comment: @Optimus1 You can use [`CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETFUNCTION`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETFUNCTION.html) to replace libcurl's use of `socket()` so you can create your own sockets with `WSASocket()` instead (and use [`CURLOPT_CLOSESOCKETFUNCTION`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CLOSESOCKETFUNCTION.html) to replace libcurl's use of `close[socket]()`, if needed). But AFAICS, libcurl does not provide a way to replace its use of recv/send I/O operations on those sockets, only replace select/poll logic for monitoring socket events.

Comment: then in theory it won't work as WSASocket uses WSASend/WSARecv and not - recv/send.

Comment: Sockets created with `WSASocket()` can be used with `recv()`/`send()`.  On Windows, `socket()` calls `WSASocket()` internally. Sockets created with `socket()` have the `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag enabled (MSDN's documentation even says so), even if subsequent code doesn't use overlapped I/O. In any case, you can always look at libcurl's source code to see what it actually uses internally.